# Cannot Import Ace Document Object in vue webpack project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, importerror, ace-editor

I want to use Ace editor in my vue and webpack project, I want to attach every file with a single `Ace Document` instance, So I do follow(default import)

```
import Ace from 'ace-builds'
```

When I want to create a Document.

```
let doc = new Ace.Ace.Document('')
```

But Chrome dev tools always tell me

`TypeError: Cannot read property Document' of undefined at FileTree.vue:177`

and `let doc = new Ace.Document('')` also not working

I have a single js file which imports Ace, and it works good, codes here.
[editor.js](https://gist.github.com/iamwwc/c55e6cc9a977bc2596d51cc3d2392b8b)

My codes(in vue methods:{}):

```
addFile (e) {
  let tree = this.$refs.maintree
  if (this.currentNode === undefined) {
    this.currentNode = tree.getNode(1)
  }
  this.openAddFilePrompt().then(({value}) => {
    let doc = new Ace.Ace.Document('')
    if (this.currentNode.data.detail.type === 'file') {
      let parentNode = this.currentNode.parent
      tree.append({detail: {type: 'file', src: '', document: doc}, id: this.maxId++, label: value}, parentNode)
      return
    }
    this.maxId++
    tree.append({detail: {type: 'file', src: '', document: doc}, id: this.maxId, label: value}, this.currentNode)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
},
```

---

This is my `d.ts` file of `ace-builds`

[image]

As you can see from the pic, Document interface put in an Ace namespace,
I import total module as Ace, So I think I should new Document Object with `new Ace.Ace.Document`, which is `defaultImport.Namespace.Interface`

---

Document interface follows. My `ace-builds` install through npm
`export interface Document extends EventEmitter`

[image]

---

`ace-builds` folder structure as follows

[image]

My question:

Why My import not working, and I cannot create the Document Object?

I tried to give you everything which can help you to solve my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this question after trying many ways.

I don't know why I cannot import `export interface` from the namespace.
I found require function in `ace.d.ts`, So I changed

`let doc = new Ace.Ace.Document('')`

to

`let Document = Ace.require('ace/document').Document`

When I need Document Object, Just `let document = new Document()`

it works.

Hope this can help others which have the same question as me.

---

*How I solved?*

I search `ace.js` about `exports.Document` and found `ace/document`
[image]

[image]